# IFTTT multiple notification triggers not working

Tags: notifications, automation, ifttt

I'm trying to trigger an IFTTT action (turning heating on/off) when I arm or disarm my alarm system. The alarm system does not offer integration with IFTTT but, since arming/disarming the system gives a notification on my phone, I decided to use the android service with the "notification from a specific app" trigger.

I can create a working trigger for when I disarm the alarm, as well as for when I arm the alarm by specifying a notification keyword, next to the app name. However, the moment I try to enable both of these at the same time, I find that only one of the two works.
Is there a limitation where you can have only one trigger checking notifications (from a specific app)? If so, are there ways around it?

I also tried location based triggers, but never got them to work (tried everything from disabling battery optimization, checking location service settings on my phone, enabling wifi/bluetooth for better accuracy and changing IFTTT apps settings).

I'm using Android 10 with the IFTTT app installed and running in the background.
I am currently unable to upgrade my android version as apparently nowadays phone companies think it is normal to stop all updates after 2-3 years, forcing you to replace perfectly good phones, which I'm not willing to do.